# Changing Font Size for ListView Column in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, fonts

I am creating a simple GUI, containing a listView which will be for use with a touch screen monitor. Therefore I require the text to be large, so it is easily readable and selectable. I can change the **Font** property of my listView to increase its size, although this also increases the column header font size in proportion (making the letters too big for the space).

Is there a method to change just the font size of the listView items and/or a means of changing the size of the text space of the column to cater for bigger letters?

I think I can use the **ListBox.DrawColumnHeader** event for this but I cannot figure out exactly how to piece it together!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've found the solution here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx

it involves using the **OwnerDraw** property to design your form. This means specifying every aspect of it. But using the same code based at the link above gives you the structure and then you just need to fill in blanks (e.g. row colour/font etc.). 

To amend the Font Size for the ListView Column, look in the **listView1_DrawColumnHeader** event. 

The code is well commented and explained well to ensure understanding  

Good Luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could help:

```
// Draws column headers.
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender,
    DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        // Store the column text alignment, letting it default
        // to Left if it has not been set to Center or Right.
        switch (e.Header.TextAlign)
        {
            case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                break;
        }

        // Draw the standard header background.
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Draw the header text.
        using (Font headerFont =
                    new Font("Helvetica", 10, FontStyle.Bold)) //Font size!!!!
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont,
                Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawcolumnheader.aspx) for more info.

Comment: This is how to do it, thanks! I found the same link with a whole sample code for anyone interested, its here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx